# validar que en un cadena se introduzca dos veces el caracter

Tags: android

Estoy realizando un teclado en Android pero requiero evitar que en la cadena se teclee como ejemplo **( 20..2)** o **(..1)**  ya que luego esa cadena lo convierto en un entero.

mi código actual

```
 valoraenviar = ".";
    valorcapturados[0] = valorcapturados[0] + valoraenviar;
    valorcapturado.setText(valorcapturados[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Podría intentar esto cada vez que presione una tecla

```
//funcion que se llama cuando presione algun caracter del teclado. Se le pasa la cadena que ha escrito en el EditText
public String escribir (String cadenaTeclado) {
    if (tienePuntoDecimal(cadenaTeclado) && cadenaTeclado.charAt(cadenaTeclado.length() - 1) == '.') {
        cadenaTeclado.substring(0, cadenaTeclado.length()-1);
    }
    return cadenaTeclado;
}

// Funcion que verifica si la cadena del EditText tenia punto decimal antes de presionar la tecla
public static boolean tienePuntoDecimal (String cadena) {
    for (int i = 0; i < cadena.length()-1; i++) {
        if (cadena.charAt(i) == '.') {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: mil gracias me funciono